# Can't figure out solution to cs50's "Recover" in C. New JPEGs are being created but I cannot view them-

Tags: c, cs50, data-recovery, recover

I am currently on the "Recover" pset in cs50 and I have tried multiple variations of my solution. The assignment is to recover 50 JPEG files that were deleted from a memory card. We are instructed to check the first 4 bytes of each 512 byte pass of fread to indicate the start of a JPEG file and to write it to a new file. Once it reaches another 4 bytes that match, we are suppose to close the previous file and write to a new one until reaching EOF (the data from the memory card is provided to us in a file called card.raw).

Below is my current solution. My confusion is that I am able to produce exactly 50 JPEGS upon running my program, as described. However, when I go to open any of the new files, I am met with an error in VS Code, which I will include below my code. Any help would be appreciated here-
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover IMAGE\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *forensic = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (forensic == NULL)
    {
        printf("File was not found\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *currentFile;
    currentFile = NULL;
    int jpegCount = 1;
    char *filename = NULL;
    filename = malloc(8 * sizeof(char));

    BYTE buffer[512];
    while (fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 512, forensic) != 0)
    {
        // Check for matching 4 bytes, indicating start of a new JPEG
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            // If file exists, close it and start a new one
            if (currentFile != NULL)
            {
                fclose(currentFile);
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", jpegCount);
                currentFile = fopen(filename, "w");
                jpegCount++;
            }
            // If no file exists yet, create one
            else
            {
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", jpegCount);
                currentFile = fopen(filename, "w");
                jpegCount++;
            }
        }
        // If file exists, write to it
        if (currentFile != NULL)
        {
            BYTE wBuffer[512];
            fwrite(wBuffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, currentFile);
        }
    }
    fclose(currentFile);
    fclose(forensic);
    free(filename);
    return 0;
}
```

`
Again, my program successfully produces 50 new JPEGs, but when I try to open them in VS Code I get the following error:

Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service workers: NotSupportedError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://0foennjt10in3q0224oduooshmepdo2jsp1eg131ejbmkj7a2i7k.vscode-cdn.net/stable/8fa188b2b301d36553cbc9ce1b0a146ccb93351f/out/vs/workbench/contrib/webview/browser/pre/') with script ('https://0foennjt10in3q0224oduooshmepdo2jsp1eg131ejbmkj7a2i7k.vscode-cdn.net/stable/8fa188b2b301d36553cbc9ce1b0a146ccb93351f/out/vs/workbench/contrib/webview/browser/pre/service-worker.js?v=4&vscode-resource-base-authority=vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net&remoteAuthority=codespaces+sebdoubleu-code50-111027905-wpxr5g54pv9h9667'): The user denied permission to use Service Worker..

I would really appreciate any help here. I am a beginner and it is very possible that I have made a minor error that I'm not seeing. It is also possible that I am going about this completely wrong and need to start over. I just don't know where to go from here because I feel like I've tried everything that I can think of at this point.

Comment: You probably want `jpegCount++;` before the `sprintf`. You can reduce duplicated code by just putting the `fclose` inside the conditional. `BYTE wBuffer[512];` is incorrect, just write the buffer that you've already read the data into, `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, currentFile);`

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you for your suggestions, I made those adjustments. Also, I figured out (based on a response from another user who must have deleted their comment) that I was unable to view it in vscode but once I downloaded the files and viewed them outside of the IDE, everything worked fine. I now feel very very dumb for not having tried that first. Nonetheless, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the provided code:

`wBuffer` is declared but not initialized or filled with any data before writing. This buffer is not needed since you already have the buffer filled with the content you want to write.
The incrementation of the **jpegCount** variable should start from `0`, not `1`. This will ensure that the first file is named `000.jpg`.
You're not checking the result of the `fopen` function when creating or opening a new JPEG file. Always good to ensure you're not dealing with a `NULL` pointer.
Here's the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover IMAGE\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *forensic = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (forensic == NULL)
    {
        printf("File was not found\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *currentFile = NULL;
    int jpegCount = 0; // Start counting from 0
    char *filename = malloc(8 * sizeof(char));
    if (filename == NULL)
    {
        fclose(forensic);
        printf("Memory allocation error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    BYTE buffer[512];
    while (fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, forensic) == 512) // Using sizeof(BYTE) for clarity
    {
        // Check for matching 4 bytes, indicating start of a new JPEG
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            // If file exists, close it before starting a new one
            if (currentFile != NULL)
            {
                fclose(currentFile);
            }

            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", jpegCount);
            currentFile = fopen(filename, "w");

            if (currentFile == NULL)
            {
                free(filename);
                fclose(forensic);
                printf("Error creating file\n");
                return 1;
            }

            jpegCount++;
        }

        // If file exists, write to it
        if (currentFile != NULL)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, currentFile); // Write using the original buffer
        }
    }

    // Close any open files
    if (currentFile != NULL)
    {
        fclose(currentFile);
    }

    fclose(forensic);
    free(filename);

    return 0;
}
```

I've incorporated error checks and streamlined the code by removing redundancies.