# recovering JPEG memory from memory card in C

Tags: c, algorithm, cs50

I'm writing this code to be able to recover(JPEGs_ memory from a memory card that has deleted them.

My code compiles and is able to run; however, the output images never load.

I tried doing debugging, but I can't seem to see what the issue could be.

Perhaps some pointers on how to debug code that only appears to indicate a problem after the code has produced an output would be useful. (if this indeed is what I am missing)

What is there that I could be missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

const int BLOCKSIZE = 512;

FILE *img = NULL;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Check if there is only 1 argument entered
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover ###.jpg\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //open memorry card and ensure that it's readable
    FILE *raw_memory = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (raw_memory == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file\n");
        return 2;
    }

        //Repeat until the end of card:

        uint8_t *buffer = malloc(BLOCKSIZE);
        int jpg_counter = 0;
        bool jpg_found = false;
        while (true) //Read 512 bytes into a buffer
        {

            size_t bytes_read = fread (buffer, 1, BLOCKSIZE, raw_memory);

             // If end of raw_memory reached, exit loop
            if (bytes_read < BLOCKSIZE)
            {
                break;
            }


            // If start of new JPG
            if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
            {
                //Open new raw_memory and start writing


                 //If first JPG raw_memory
                 if (jpg_counter == 0)
                 {
                    //Open new raw_memory and start writing
                    char str[100];
                    sprintf(str, "%03i.jpg", jpg_counter);
                    img = fopen(str, "w");
                    if (img == NULL)
                    {
                        printf("Could not open jpeg file\n");
                        return 3;
                    }
                    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, img);
                    jpg_counter++;
                    jpg_found = true;
                 }
                 else //close previously file and open a new one
                 {
                    fclose(img);
                    jpg_found = false;

                    char str[100];
                    sprintf(str, "%03i.jpg", jpg_counter);

                    img = fopen(str, "w");
                    if (img == NULL)
                    {
                        printf("Could not open jpeg file\n");
                        return 4;
                    }
                    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, img);
                    jpg_found = true;
                    jpg_counter++;

                 }
            }

            else
            {
                if (jpg_found)
                {
                    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, img);
                }

            }

        }


    fclose(img);
    fclose(raw_memory);
    free(buffer);


}
```

Comment: if the file is deleted how do you expect to be able to open it?

Comment: @where exactly would you say I am deleting the file?

Comment: If it was so easy to recover lost pictures from the card .......

Comment: @Sizwe you wrote that: 
*"I'm writing this code to be able to take memory from a memory card that has deleted JPEGs and be able to retrieve it."*

Comment: `buffer` is a pointer, so `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of a pointer, not the number of bytes in the buffer. If you declare the buffer as an array `uint8_t buffer[BLOCKSIZE];` then the `malloc` and `free` aren't needed, and `sizeof(buffer)` will work as expected.

Comment: `FILE *raw_memory = fopen(argv[1], "r");` you open the file. If the file exists there is nothing to recover. To recover the deleted files you need to read the SD card on the sector level as your files from the file system point of view do not exist

Comment: @user3386109 - Thank you. I replaced `buffer` with `BLOCKSIZE`  and that was my issue. 
Thanks again for the tip!

Comment: @user3386109 - may I post your comment as the answer?

Comment: I think some comments are assuming that `argv[1]` is a jpg filename. It is not. It is probably more some `/dev/sda?` or somethng like that. And, yes, it is that easy to recover a jpg (well, most jpg. It doesn't work all the times. That is the principle behind tools like `photorec`: search for JPG signature, read its size from header, and assume it is contiguous on the disk (which is not guaranteed, but is more often than not the case)

Comment: in the first sentence

Comment: @chrslg "assume it is contiguous on the disk (which is not guaranteed, but is more often than not the case)." YMMV. Alternately deleting some old photos and creating new ones may cause fragmentation, turning the memory card's file system into a jigsaw puzzle. I'm afraid that's what's bugging OP.

Comment: @RuudHelderman, well yes, that can happen too. Although this kind of operation is usually done just after the accident, and when we refrain from using the card since. Besides, what is bugging the OP is the classical confusion `sizof≠len`. I think that has been covered already. The tag `cs50`, unless I am mistaken about what it means, tend to prove that the task (recovering the jpg) should not be impossible, so it was probably not overwritten. Anyway, whatever the reason why it is possible, that is how `photorec` works, so it is not that naive to try that way, that was my point.

Comment: @chrslg You are right; I found another student struggling with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74307011/cant-figure-out-solution-to-cs50s-recover-in-c-new-jpegs-are-being-created

Comment: @Sizwe "How to debug code that only appears to indicate a problem after the code has produced an output." By focusing on the output rather than the code. Concatenate the output files, make a hex dump of the result, then use a good diff tool to compare it with a hex dump of the input. Actually _seeing_ the differences should give you a good clue as to what went wrong.

Comment: @Sizwe Yes, of course. Sorry for the delay, I was called away after posting that comment. btw, I posted a comment because I know that this is a duplicate many times over, but didn't have time to look for a good match. I just spent some time looking, and found some half decent duplicates, but none of them were a perfect match.

Comment: if you want the real thing then you need to code `UNDELETE` command for filetype you use in your memory card ... so you need to read and decode the FAT find the deleted filenames with `jpg,jpeg,jfif` extentions and read their sectors in order into your buffer then save it ... so you should start with file system used what is it?  FAT11/16/32 , NTFS, EX?, other ? find its specs and decode ... in some cases its enough to just mark the deleted file as not deleted or copy its entry from backup FAT ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`buffer` is a pointer, so `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of a pointer, not the number of bytes in the buffer. If you declare the buffer as an array `uint8_t buffer[BLOCKSIZE]`; then the `malloc` and `free` aren't needed, and `sizeof(buffer)` will work as expected

Replacing `sizeofbuffer` with `BLOCKSIZE` should allocate enough bytes for the code to work

(credit: @user3386109)

Comment: @user3386109 - Pardon my delay as well. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

A) Since you need 512 elements, instead of `uint8_t *buffer = malloc(BLOCKSIZE);` do at global level

```
uint8_t tmp[BLOCKSIZE];    
uint8_t *buffer = &tmp[0];
```

B) Instead of `fread (buffer, 1, BLOCKSIZE, raw_memory)`; do `fread(buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), BLOCKSIZE, raw_memory);` The same applies for `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, img);` to `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), BLOCKSIZE, img);` This per documentation https://manual.cs50.io/3/fwrite

C) I think that many problems arise from the design of what is inside of this if statement (line 45)

```
    // If start of new JPG
    if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
    {
            //Open new raw_memory and start writing


             //If first JPG raw_memory
             if (jpg_counter == 0)
             {
```

Try:

1. Changing `if (jpg_counter == 0)` for `if (jpg_counter > 0)` simplifying the if statements so only if there are already photo files you can close them, no else.
2. Getting rid of `char str[100];` Instead try `char str[8];` since 000.jpg is 7 chars long + '\0'.
3. You don't need `jpg_found = false;` on line 70, since that var is only useful before finding the first image.

Hope that's useful...

Edit 1: since buffer needs to be a pointer in `fread` and `fwrite` of BlOCKSIZE times the type, better that buffer points to an `uint8_t` array of size BLOCKSIZE, instead of using malloc.

Edit 2: Thus, no further need of `free(buffer)`;

Comment: *... do at global level

`uint8_t tmp[BLOCKSIZE];    
uint8_t *buffer = &tmp[0];`*?!?  Why introduce variables at a global level when there's absolutely zero need for them to be global?

Comment: For style sake, but may work inside main too.